# Structure from motion vs Structure and motion

Tags: image-processing, video-processing, 3d-reconstruction

I would like to know the main difference between "structure from motion" and "structure and motion". I think it is the same thing because the result is same and the methods are also same as it is to reconstruct in 3D the environment. But in some papers I have seen sfm in others I have seen sam.

Thank you.

Comment: I have never heard of "structure and motion" and it doesn't make any sense to me. it would help if you would name and linke the source where you found that term...

Comment: For example : 
Structure and Motion from Line Segments in
Multiple Images : https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cjtaylor/PUBLICATIONS/pdfs/TaylorPAMI95.pdf

Comment: The publication proposes a solution to the structure from motion problem that also explicitly solves for the camera motion. That may be why the authors named it structure "and" motion.